Taylor series expnasion
I was given the following question :
Evaluate the series expansion of $f(x) = \ln(\frac{1-x}{1+x^2})$ and determine the radius of convergence.
So my first move was to split the logarithm into $\ln(1-x) - \ln(1+x^2)$ and then substitute each one into the famous $\ln(1+x)$ expansion which gives :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{x^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$
But I got a little stuck here, i need to get it to the form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$. Any ideas? Are rearrangements an option here?

For $n$ odd the coefficient is $-\frac  1n$. For $n$ even you have to combine one term from the first sum and one from the second.

Just take$$a_n=\begin{cases}-\frac1n&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\-\frac1n-\frac{(-1)^{n/2+1}}{n/2}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Of course, instead of $\displaystyle-\frac{(-1)^{n/2}+1}{n/2}$, it is more natural to have $\displaystyle2\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}n$.

That's what I meant when I said rearrangements - but is that a "legal" move? Isn't that ok only if we know that the series converges absolutely?

I made no rearrangement. Instead, I used the fact that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n}}n=0\times x+x^2+0\times x^3-\frac{x^4}2+\cdots$$and then I added minus this series to the series$$-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots$$None of this (adding zeros to a series and adding two series term by term) requires absolute convergence.

I understand, thank you!
